# USB hub IC overcurrent Pin: active LOW or active HIGH?

Tags: usb, usb-hub, over-current

I am using USB2517 - USB 2.0 Hi-Speed 7-Port Hub Controller IC to make a USB 2.0 hub.

What I do not understand (or its missing from the IC's datasheet), is Pins OCS[7:1]_N, which are "Input from external current monitor indicating an over-current condition".

[image: overcurrent active low or high]

I do not understand if that pin is Active Low or active high. Do I need to send a 0V signal to indicate there is no overcurrent, or a 3.3V signal to indicate there is no overcurrent?

As a note, the datasheet says this pin has a internal pull up resistor, but this does not help me understand what level signal I need to send to activate the overcurrent condition.

I guess since there is a internal pull-up, then 0V are used to indicate overcurrent?

This information from the datasheet is either missing or its plain obvious.

Otherwise, I will have to contact microchip to ask for support.

Comment: Even if _N suffixes are not given, the **{Note}** gives a clue: Since those terminals are inputs with internal pull-ups, they see logic-hi when left floating. So it's obvious that the inputs should be active-low.

Comment: I know, I was thinking about that, but I then said "wait, what if the IC wants to keep the overcurrent protection passively active by pulling the pin high?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _N typically indicates 'negated' and thereby it is active LOW.

Comment: Okay, it was plain obvious. Thanks!